# Native HTML5 compiler for qt platform

Tags: c++, angularjs, linux, html, qt

I am making an application using qt on a Linux based OS for a touch device. I am currently using Qt web view to host an HTML 5  + AngularJS application. Are there any compilers to compile a web app for qt platform, like how ionic converts angular app into native code for ios and android.

Comment: If you pack your HTML code into qt resources, you will get an standalone executable with the HTML code in it. Is it that what you need?

Comment: Not essentially, I was looking for a general purpose compiler which can be used to create native qt apps from a web project. But this helps too. Thanks